# Set urxvt shell without chsh?

Tags: shell, zsh, urxvt

I want to use bash as my default shell (so that it's simpler in tty) but I want to use zsh when I'm in X using urxvt. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send zsh in as a command when launching urxvt:

```
urxvt -e /path/to/zsh
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a check in you `~/.bashrc` if it is running in *(u)rxvt*. And if so, replace *bash* with *zsh*:

```
if [[ "$TERM" == *rxvt* ]]; then
   exec zsh
fi
```